# Facebook App as Page Tab

Tags: php, facebook

I'm a little confused.

I have created an app, and edited the profiles to add the tab. I created a quick sample app at app.facebook.com/myapp/tab.php with this code:

```
<?php

require_once '../php/facebook.php'; 

$apiKey = 'key'; 
$secret = 'secret'; 
$facebook = new Facebook($apiKey, $secret);
print 'Works';

?>
```

I cannot seem to find out how to add the tap to the page I have create. I click the + and there is nothing there, I've tried searching in the + tab.

Any ideas about adding the app as a tab?

Comment: Fixed it!

Forgot to go to the application profile and click "Add to Page".

Comment: Can you help me telling me WHERE IS that "Add to Page" ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `profile.setFBML` providing it the fbml for your tab, and give users of your canvas page the option to add it with a `fb:add-section-button`

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile